# Spring MVC return HTML code to insert inside main page

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm using Spring MVC in my project and HTML and Javascript/AngularJs for front-end page.
At the moment I have the controllers that return the page like this:

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER','ROLE_FACILITY')")
@RequestMapping(value = {"/reservations"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String reservationPage(){        
    return "reservation";
}
```

All the page have a fragment with the sidebar and top navbar, the problem is that all the page reload this fragment instead I'd like to have this fragment fixed and insert the html page inside its content. If spring mvc return all the page, How can achieve this?
This is a simple page with the fragment:

```
    <!-- Header nd menu fragment -->
    <div th:replace="../fragments/dashboard-header :: dashboard-header"></div>

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>500 Error Page</h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">500 error</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            <div class="error-page">
                <h2 class="headline text-red">500</h2>
                <div class="error-content">
                    <h3>
                        <i class="fa fa-warning text-red"></i> Oops! Something went
                        wrong.
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        <font size=4> We will work on fixing that right away.
                            Meanwhile, you may <a th:href="@{/dashboard}">return to
                                dashboard.</a>
                        </font>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.error-page -->

        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
```

Comment: hm, change to JSP and include? :)

Comment: is it not possibile without jsp? And with jsp hown can include the returned page?

Comment: you can see [here](https://www.javatips.net/blog/difference-between-static-include-and-dynamic-include) where they show examples of static and dynamic includes. try them and see if they work

Comment: @luca  you can try `sitemesh`,define a template and then it will warp the return page automaticlly

Comment: Are you submitting an AJAX  request ? Angular JS frameworks typically expect JSON data from the controller, once the page is loaded.

Comment: ajax/jsp includes/configure apache tiles

Comment: yes I have ajac request. Each page has different import, I'd like to avoid the sidebar reloading because it is ugly to show and because it reload avatars with several KB. I can use ajax request and put html inside the content from javascript but I have to import all the dependecies in the main page.